# Failed to move working directory snapshot { ss=_UPGRADING_TABLE_SYSTEM.MUTEX table=SYSTEM.MUTEX type=DISABLED }

Tags: hbase, apache-phoenix

While creating schema or table I am getting this error:

> Failed to move working directory snapshot{
>   ss=_UPGRADING_TABLE_SYSTEM.MUTEX table=SYSTEM.MUTEX type=DISABLED }

So because of this error it is not creating the schema or table.

**Java program:**

```
Properties connectionProps = new Properties();
connectionProps.put("phoenix.schema.isNamespaceMappingEnabled", "true");
connectionProps.put("phoenix.schema.mapSystemTablesToNamespace", "true");
connection = 
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:phoenix:localhost",connectionProps);
statement = connection.createStatement();
statement.executeUpdate("CREATE SCHEMA MYSCHEMA");
connection .commit();
```

**hdfs-site.xml**

```
<property>
        <name>phoenix.schema.isNamespaceMappingEnabled</name>
        <value>true</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>phoenix.schema.mapSystemTablesToNamespace</name>
        <value>true</value>
    </property>
</code>
```

*HBase version : 1.2.6

Phoenix version : 4.10.0-HBase-1.2.0

Windows : 8.1*

Comment: I've had similar issues, and rolled a restart of my HBase cluster.

Comment: actually I am running hbase and phoenix in stand alone mode.And I am performing all operations on hbase using phoenix with java apis.

Comment: in that case, it's worth turning on all the logging in log4j.properties - turn info to ALL and remove comments #

Comment: Hbase and Phoenix are working fine on Mac system but on windows I am getting this error.